# Log all of the commands run by Linux build process

Tags: linux, makefile

For what I am seeking to do with the Linux kernel, it is necessary that I log all of the commands run by the build process. The Linux build system, as it is written, does not display the commands that it runs, like invocations `ld` and the compiler. Instead, it will print lines like this:

```
LD usr/built-in.o
```

I want to be able to see those printed to the terminal, but I'd also like to log the actual commands to a file so I can see what is run to, say, link the initial RAM filesystem into `vmlinux` or the order in which object files are linked. How can I do this?

The purpose of this is to figure the particular object files I need and what commands to run in order to make different builds with different initial RAM filesystem contents without having to start from scratch. So, if the CPIO was produced by running `cpio $dir > initramfs.cpio` and then the final kernel image was produced by running `ld code.o initramfs.cpio`, then I will have the object files that I don't need to rebuild and the way to combine them with the initramfs to make the final kernel image.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `V=1` to `make`.

`make V=1 ...`